# Strapi v4 REST API :GET image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, strapi

please I am working with the new strapi v4 and... In the old versions of strapi all I needed to do in order to get the image from my collection type was to get it like:
`<img src={config.baseURL + product?.productImg?.formats?.thumbnail?.url} />`
but when I try to do the same now, it gives me the url address, but the response says

```
{"data":null,"error":{"status":404,"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Not Found","details":{}}}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized it. In my config file, I had the *baseURL* as `'localhost:1337/api'`. However, for images, you must request without the `'/api'` so the request should be just `'localhost:1337/{imageUrl}'` url/image route

Comment: OMG! Thanks.
After spending hours I found this solution. It should be clearly mentioned somewhere in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

with strapi v4 u need to manually populate your rest api with images otherwise it's restricted due to security reasons :

`localhost:1337/api/posts?populate=*`

then you will get images on your endpoint

Comment: well, yep I figured after reading docs :D... although I was not able to find out that you need that `/api/` in the middle of the requests...

Comment: yah for version 4